# How can I append a Meta Viewport tag to the masked domain forwarding iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, mobile

There are similar questions on Stack Overflow regarding the way masked domain forwarding affects Meta Viewport tags, but I've yet to find a solution to the way the forwarding removes the Viewport tag and the page's responsiveness. In order to mask the page, an `iframe` is inserted which contains the content of the referenced site. The problem is that this `iframe` is placed within a new `head` tag which no longer contains a meta viewport.

I've found from some experimentation in the built in HTML inspector in Chrome, that if I add in this meta tag, the page will display correctly again. So, it seems to me all I would need to do is add a Meta Viewport to the page when it loads like so:

```
<script>
function setViewport(){
var meta = document.createElement('meta');
meta.name= "viewport";
meta.content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
}
window.onload = setViewport;
</script>
```

However, this doesn't work. When I run the JS in the console, the tag is added in and the page re-formats nicely, but if I actually add the JS to my code it doesn't get fired off.

I assume I'm not placing the script in the right location. I'm placing it in my header include file right now, but this include ends up within the iframe when the page is rendered so I could see why it wouldn't have an effect on the page. So my question is, is there a location in my code where I could place this so it runs after the forwarder re-formats the page, or is there a function other than `onload` that might accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS will never work because you will have cross origin request blocked (unless both the iframe content (ur target website) and the godaddy domain are of the same origin - which is not in almost all cases. Hence, there is no way I can see to add a meta tag via js from content site.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, try use:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    setViewport();
});
```

Comment: The problem is that, though the page being iframed does include JQuery, the wrapper that GoDaddy creates does not, so the solution must be done with Javascript.